# $L^1$ limit of non-negative functions is nonnegative?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $u_n \geq 0$ and $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega $ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. 
Can I say that limit function $u\geq 0$?

Comment: You can show that convergence in $L_1$ implies almost everywhere convergence of a subsequence. I urge you to try this exercise, but the above is clear once we do this exercise.

Comment: Certaily not everywhere. You can however conclude $u\ge 0$ a.e. (The boundedness of $\Omega$ is not important.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as long as we agree that $u\ge 0$ a.e. is the most we can hope for.

Assume $\{u<0\}$ has positive measure. Because $\{u<0\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{u<-1/k\},$ $\{u<-1/k_0\}$ has positive measure for some $k_0.$ Thus

$$\int_\Omega |u_n-u|\, d\mu \ge \int_{\{u<-1/k_0\}} |u_n-u|\, d\mu = \int_{\{u<-1/k_0\}} (u_n-u)\, d\mu  \ge (1/k_0)\mu(\{u<-1/k_0\})$$

for all $n.$ That contradicts $u_n \to u$ in $L^1.$

Comment: Thanks...it is clear to me now...@zhw

Answer (score 2):

Since $u_n\to u$ in $L^1$, there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ such that $u_{n_k}\to u$ almost everywhere. And since $u_{n_k}\geq 0$ almost everywhere for each $k$, it follows that $u\geq 0$ almost everywhere.